# Why does it return max for 2.0 in java?

Tags: java

I'm running this java code below and it is supposed to give me the max for 34.5.Instead, it's 2.0. Weird! Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this code? Thanks.

```
public class VarargsDemo {

public static void main(String args[]){
        printMax(34.5, 3, 5, 6, 2);
        printMax(new double[]{1,2,3});
}

public static void printMax(double...numbers){
    if (numbers.length==0){
        System.out.println("No argument passed");
        return;
    }

    double result=numbers[0];
    for (int i=1; i<numbers.length;i++)
        result=numbers[i];
    System.out.println("the max value is "+result);
}
```

}

Output:

```
the max value is 2.0
the max value is 3.0
```

Comment: You aren't even doing any comparison, just overwriting the value in result with next double number.

Comment: Agh the problem is someone is going to write out the answer for him, and he won't learn anything.

Comment: Maybe you meant to sort the array first?

Comment: What have you done to debug it??

Comment: from this stupid mistake, I know I must do comparison to get the max or min. Thank you guys!

Comment: @touchdown I suggest you first think logically and NOT in terms of code about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i=1; i<numbers.length;i++)
    result=numbers[i];
```

this makes `result` the last element of the array, not the greatest one...

You probably wanted

```
for (int i=1; i<numbers.length;i++)
    result = Math.max(numbers[i], result);
```

Comment: @touchdown, you can use Math.max(double,double) or write up your comparison. I'd suggest you write your own for the learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

You're just iterating from the second element of your `varargs` array until the last and printing that one.

Spare yourself the trouble, and use something like:

```
double lower = 1.0d;
double higher = 2.0d;
System.out.println(Math.max(lower, higher));
```

... and of course adapt it to your `varargs` method - I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `double max(double[] array)` method of [org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#max%28double%5b%5d%29).

> It Returns the maximum value in an array.